# Can i change the value of the variable "a" in if genre == '1: generate' and affect the variable "a" in another if genre == '2: adjust'?

Tags: python, variables, streamlit

Can i change the value of the variable "a" in if genre == '1: generate' and affect the variable "a" in another if genre == '2: adjust' ?

```
if genre == '1: generate':
    st.subheader('generate')
    _, palette_hex = t2p_demo.generate(
        np.array(image), input_words, category)

    palette_img = []
    for item in palette_hex:
        palette_img.append(Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), color=item))

    st.image(palette_img)

    st.subheader('generate: ')
    
    a=[]
    for item in palette_hex:
        a.append(item)
    st.write(' '.join(a))
    
   
if genre == '2: adjust':
    st.subheader('adjust')
    st.write(' '.join(a))
  
    st.write('adjust:')
    words = st.text_input('adjust：', value=(' '.join(a)),
                          max_chars=None, key=None, type='default')
    st.write('adjust: ', words)
```

Comment: Of course. It's the same variable.

Comment: You have tags `global-variables` and `local-variables`. Local variables are only in functions. Where is the function?

Comment: No, because it's not possible for both of those blocks to be executed.  (Well, unless `genre` is something with a very unusual `__eq__` implementation!)

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you are trying to do, but, in order to make changes from one execution (when genre=='1 ...') permanent on another (when genre=='2 ...') you can use `session_state` as follows:

```py
if genre == '1: generate':
    st.session_state.a=[]
    for item in palette_hex:
        st.session_state.a.append(item)
    st.write(' '.join(st.session_state.a))
 
if genre == '2: adjust':
    st.subheader('adjust')
    st.write(' '.join(st.session_state.a))
```

This usage might force you to define 'a' in the session_state, which can be done at the start of the script and as follows:

```py
if 'a' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.a = [] # or any other default value
```